# What are the levels in multi index data frame called?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

What are the different levels on my picture for a multiindex dataframe called? And how can access each level using pivot_table.

Also, how would I add 'Ticker' just above date

[image]

Comment: via `tuple()` for example `df.loc[:,('Close','A')]`

Comment: you have multi indexed column....so the yellow part is level0 and black part is level1

Answer (score 0):

The levels are named from `0`, `1`, etc. onwards, with the uppermost level as `0`

You can access each level by [`pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html). For example, you can use the following to get the level `1` (second level from top) of column index you want:

```
df.columns.get_level_values(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have multi indexed column....so the yellow part is `level 0` and black part is `level 1`

so if you want to access values then use(for example):

```
df.loc[:,('Close','A')]    #for selecting a single column
#OR
df.loc[:, df.columns.get_level_values(1)=='A']  #for selecting all values at level 1 where column is 'A'
#OR
df.loc[:, df.columns.get_level_values(0)=='Close']  #for selecting all values at level 0 where column is 'Close'
```

If you want to make single level index then you have to drop either `level 0` or `level 1`

```
df=df.droplevel(0,1)  #for removing the columns name in yellow part
#OR
df=df.droplevel(1,1)  #for removing the columns name in black part
```

If you don't want to lose any level then you can join these 2 levels to make it single level so that you can access columns like you do normally:

```
df.columns=df.columns.map('_'.join)
#here the both level is joined by '_' btw you can use any custum character for joining levels
```

For more Information kindly refer to [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#hierarchical-indexing-multiindex)

[This article](https://towardsdatascience.com/accessing-data-in-a-multiindex-dataframe-in-pandas-569e8767201d) may also help